# Android "smallest width" layout for tablets not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have two `activity_menu.xml` one for tablets in `layout-sw600dp` and another in `layout`. The layout for tablets is never loaded (I even tested it on 4K xxxhdpi emulator). I would also add that all my layouts are portrait.
Is there anything that maybe needs to be changed in manifest, gradle or added to a file?

I didn't try layout-large, but I want to keep it "modern", not using deprecated methods.

Comment: What is the way you made your layouts portrait? Did you set it programmatically or add `port` qualifier to `layout`s directories?

Answer (score 1):

> The layout for tablets is never loaded (I even tested it on 4K xxxhdpi emulator).

I do not know what you consider 4K to be, as there seem to be multiple definitions.

However, `xxxhdpi` is 640dpi. 640dp is 2560 pixels at `xxxhdpi` density. Both 4K definitions cited on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution) have the smallest width as 2160 pixels. Hence, this emulator would not use `res/layout-sw640dp/`, as it is not big enough.

To create an emulator that will use `res/layout-sw640dp/` resources, you need to create one whose smallest width is 640dp or larger. So, for example, if you create an `mdpi` emulator, where 1dp = 1px, you would need to choose a resolution where both sides are 640px or larger.